# Display full screen loading widget in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to show full-screen loading view in flutter while API calling. But when I add loading widget in scaffold body it appears after appbar and bottom navigator.

I am spending lots of time for display loading view in full-screen. Also, I want to prevent back action while API calling.

Answer (score 9):

Well, since you're using `Scaffold`, then make use of its `showDialog()` method.

It has a property called `barrierDismissible` that if you set as false, the user won't be able to close or interact with the screen outside of it.

```dart
void _openLoadingDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Once you're done with the API loading, call `Navigator.pop(context);` to dismiss the dialog.

To prevent the user from clicking the back button on the Dialog, dismissing it, envelop your `Scaffold` inside a `WillPopScope` widget and implement the onWillPop function.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
      ),
      onWillPop: _onBackButton
  );
}

Future<bool> _onBackButton() {
  // Implement your logic
  return Future.value(false);
}
```

If you return false on it, the user won't be able to press the back button. So use any logic you desire, e.g '*If I'm loading return false, otherwise return true*'.

Comment: Using `showDialog` can mess up the context. check https://pub.dev/packages/screen_loader.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Full-screen loader**: Best solution to display a full screen loader is to use package
   https://pub.dev/packages/screen_loader.
2. **Prevent back action while loading**: This package this package provides a variable `isLoading`, use it to prevent navigating back. eg:

```dart
// --------------- some_screen.dart ---------------
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:screen_loader/screen_loader.dart';

class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}

class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> with ScreenLoader<SomeScreen> {
  getData() {
    this.performFuture(NetworkService.callApi);
  }

  @override
  Widget screen(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
          // your beautiful design..
          ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        return !isLoading;
      },
    );
  }
}

// --------------- app_api.dart ---------------
class NetworkService {
  static Future callApi() async {

  }
}
```

**NOTE**: You'll need to see the definition of `performFuture` to see how it works for different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dialog for full screen loading [progress_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/progress_dialog#-readme-tab-)

Answer (score -3):

Did you not think of removing the Scaffold for the loading screen?

Comment: In my app, there is no loading screen, but when I call API I need to show loader like https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD. while API calling and also prevent back.

Comment: So what do you want? A dialog? Or a fullscreen loading view? If you want a full screen loading view, you need the Scaffold to only be part of the normal view, with it not in the widget tree in the loading view

Comment: @DhavalPatel It seems you never solved your problem. As I said before, your "loader" needs to be outside the scaffold. Simple as that.